# Множественное или единственное число у прилагательного

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, единственное-множественное-число

*Учитель говорит, что ученик подходит по голосу во второе (вторые?) сопрано*.
 Как будет правильно написать прилагательное в данном случае?

Answer (score 1):

Сопрано - средний род, единственное число, из чего следует, что и числительное "второе", приложенное к данному существительному,  так же среднего рода.
Правильно написать - второе.

Answer (score 0):

В хорах партии Сопрано I состоят в основном из лирических сопрано. Драматические голоса помещаются в партию Сопрано II. По аналогии с лирическим меццо-сопрано, образующим в хоре партию первых Альтов, можно сказать, что драматические голоса помещаются в партию вторых Сопрано.

(https://studopedia.su/9_35138_harakteristika-golosov-hora.html)

Answer (score 0):

Здесь все зависит от смысла, которы вкладывается в слово «сопрано» — это партия в хоре или тембр голоса — от этого зависит и число прилагательного. Если имеется в виду «подходит в партию вторых сопрано», то и ответ очевиден: «во вторые сопрано». Глагол «подходит» и предлог «во» склоняют именно к такому смыслу.